# .Net Core 3.0 WebAPI Attribute routing problem

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

Client ID: 1147947322680754
PAT: 2a22564a5ce15dd46ee66468097ad0b9

Trying to configure attribute routing on my new api could not get that done after hours of reading and digging in sources. You are my last resort. What do I do wrong?

I configured app.UseMvc(); in startup and using following code...

Here is how BaseController looks;

```cs
[ApiController]
public abstract class GKControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public GKControllerBase(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        this._accessor = accessor;
    }

}
```

Here is how UserController.cs looks;

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("Services/[controller]/[action]")]
public class UserController : GKControllerBase
{
    public UserController(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) : base(accessor)
    {
    }
    [HttpGet] //Services/User/Logout
    [UserTypeFilter(UserType.Anonymous, UserTypeFilterMode.SingularDeny, ErrorMessage = "You are not logged in!")]
    public object Logout()
    {
        if (GKManagers.SessionManager.TryGetCurrentUser(base.HttpContext, out User user))
        {
            GKManagers.SessionManager.Logout(base.HttpContext, user.UniqueId);

            return this.Answer(HttpStatusCode.OK, null, "Logout successful");
        }
        return this.Answer(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }

    [HttpGet("{username}/{password}")] //Services/User/Login/username/password
    [UserTypeFilter(UserType.Anonymous, UserTypeFilterMode.SingularAllow, ErrorMessage = "You are already logged in!")]
    public object Login(string username, string password)
    {
        if (GKManagers.SessionManager.TryLogin(base.HttpContext, username, password, out User user))
            return this.Answer(HttpStatusCode.OK, user, "Login successful");
        return this.Answer(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }

}
```

Here is how GroupController.cs looks;

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("Services/[controller]/[action]")]
public class GroupController : GKControllerBase
{
    public GroupController(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) : base(accessor)
    {
    }


    [HttpGet("{groupID:int}")] //Services/Group/Join/1
    [UserTypeFilter(UserType.Anonymous, UserTypeFilterMode.SingularDeny, ErrorMessage = "You are not logged in!")]
    [PermissionFilter
        (Data.Enums.ApplicationContext.Membership_Group, Operation.CanJoin, ErrorMessage = "You are not permitted to join the %groupName%. You might be already in it.")]
    public object Join(Int32 groupID)
    {
        if (GKManagers.SessionManager.TryGetCurrentUser(this.HttpContext, out User currentUser))
        {
            GKManagers.Database.Membership.GroupMembership.Add(new GroupMembership()
            {
                Group = groupID,
                User = currentUser.UserId,
                IsActive = true,
                JoinDate = DateTime.Now,
                LastActionDate = DateTime.Now,
                Status = (Int32)Status.Active,
            });

        }
        return this.Answer(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

I am trying to configure route to be looking like the commented section next to the attribute.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no problem when I use your code (remove filter and unrelated code) in an asp.net core 3.0 web api project.Have you tried in a new project?Do those filter attributes have an effect on routing?

Answer (score 0):

Change controller routing to:

```
[Route("Services/[controller]")]
```

And on actions try this:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")] // Services/User/Logout
[HttpGet("[action]/{groupID:int}")] // Services/Group/Join/1
[HttpGet("[action]/{username}/{password}")] // Services/User/Login/username/password
```

Or like below:

```
[Route("[action]")] // Services/User/Logout
[HttpGet]

[Route("[action]/{groupID:int}")] // Services/Group/Join/1
[HttpGet]

[Route("[action]/{username}/{password}")] // Services/User/Login/username/password
[HttpGet]
```

Comment: Sorry Sir, that did not really help.

Comment: @GökhanKutucularoğlu do you see any errors or something?

Comment: No, just 404 page not found

Comment: @GökhanKutucularoğlu [Here](https://pastebin.com/RudrY5u3) I have implemented a sample controller with attribute routing and convention-based routing on different controllers, It's not exactly your answer but it's similar to your problem, It's tested and working. **Note how controllers and actions are decorated and how I've changed `app.UseMvc` method for each situation. In attribute routing it should be `app.UseMvc();`.